# How can I extract xml value @ attribute = something from python

Tags: python, xml, extract, etl

For example this is my xml

```
<p1>
     <p2>
         <name>nikki</name>
         <p3>
            <c days="1">1</c>
            <c days="3">5</c>
            <c days="7">9</c>
        </p3>
    </p2>
</p1>
```

So Far I am able to extract name  using `name = etree.XPath('/p1/p2/name/text()')(root)[0]` but how can I extract day1 , day3 and day7 to get value 1,5,7 ??

Here's my code using import etree

```
name = etree.XPath('/p1/p2/name/text()')(root)[0]

?? day1 = etree.XPath('/p1/p2/p3/c@days="1"/text()')(root)[0]
?? day3 = etree.XPath('/p1/p2/p3/c@days="3"/text()')(root)[0]
?? day7 = etree.XPath('/p1/p2/p3/c@days="7"/text()')(root)[0]

print name , day1 , day2, day7 


OUTPUT WANTED: nikki 1 5 9
```

Answer (score 2):

The `text` property of an ElementTree Element will give you the value between an element's tags. So:

```
print name, day1.text, day2.text, day7.text
```

should give you your expected output.

[Here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element) is the documentation for ElementTree Element.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using lxml. Here is a suggestion:

```
from lxml import etree

XML ="""
<p1>
     <p2>
         <name>nikki</name>
         <p3>
            <c days="1">1</c>
            <c days="3">5</c>
            <c days="7">9</c>
        </p3>
    </p2>
</p1>"""

root = etree.fromstring(XML)

name = root.xpath("p2/name")[0]
p3 = root.xpath("p2/p3")[0]
day1 = p3.xpath('c[@days="1"]')[0]
day3 = p3.xpath('c[@days="3"]')[0]
day7 = p3.xpath('c[@days="7"]')[0]

print name.text, day1.text, day3.text, day7.text
```

Output:

```
nikki 1 5 9
```

Note the [predicates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates) (the filter expressions in square brackets).

An expression such as `'/p1/p2/p3/c@days="7"/text()'` in the question is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

_f = open("your_file_path.xml", "r")
data = _f.read()
_f.close()
dom = parseString(data)

# name
name = dom.getElementsByTagName('name')[0].firstChild.data

# days
itemList = dom.getElementsByTagName("c")
for s in itemList:
    print s.attributes['days'].value

or 

day1 = dom.getElementsByTagName("c")[0].firstChild.nodeValue

or 

day1 = dom.getElementsByTagName("c")[0].firstChild.data
```

Answer (score 0):

*Try to use lxml, it has better xpath support and you are overthinking:*

```
xml=\
"""<p1>
     <p2>
         <name>nikki</name>
         <p3>
            <c days="1">1</c>
            <c days="3">5</c>
            <c days="7">9</c>
        </p3>
    </p2>
</p1>"""
import lxml.etree as et
doc=et.fromstring(xml)
print doc.xpath('.//name/text()|.//c/text()')
```

*out:*

```
['nikki', '1', '5', '9']
```

*EDIT: If you have to use standard lib, you can do:*

```
print root.find('.//name').text
print [e.text for e in root.findall('.//c')]
```

*out:*

```
nikki
['1', '5', '9']
```